# Write log of script live to file

Tags: redirect, logging, live

When I start the script **test.py > test.log**, the output is only written to the file **test.log** after the script has finished.
How do I get the output to the **test.log** file while the script is running (live)?

I have tested without success:
`./test.py > test.log`
`./test.py &> test.log`
`./test.py > test.log &`

`nohup python3 -u test.py > test.log 2>&1 &`
works. But when multiple scripts are running, all tasks are named python3. This is unfavorable eg for the **killall -9** command.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from time import sleep
for i in range(0,21):
  print(i)
  sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the discussion in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering).

In your described situation, setting the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable should do what you need.

Comment: Upon further experimentation this doesn't seem to work with your example test script, though the `-u` parameter does. Adding manual calls to sys.stdout.flush() and the flush=True statement to the print call also do not appear to help, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ok thx. When I run the script with **python3 -u test.py > test.log** it works. But the task is named **python3**.